# Powershell script file from .csv to 3 different ous

Tags: powershell, csv, organizational-unit

So I have a problem with the code provided below. 
I have a .csv file named 0010798M and in it I have 3 files with the names of name,surname,ou.

In the ou section from the .csv file I have 3 different ous with the name of Account, Sales, Management.

My code is provided in this link: https://pastebin.com/D0Naiccr

```
#Import the PowerShell module containing AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
write-host "Start Process"
write-host "-------------------------------------"
try {
    #Read the CSV file
    $csvPath = "C:\0010798M.csv"
    $csvData = import-csv $csvPath
    write-host "Reading the CSV file......"
    #Loop through all items in the CSV items

    ForEach ($user In $csvData) {
        $saMAccountName = $user.sAMAccountName
        #Check if the User exists
        $ADuser = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$saMAccountName)"
        If ($ADuser -eq $Null) {
            #Create user using New-ADUser cmdlet
            $userPrincipalName =  $user.sAMAccountName + "@adatum.com"
            New-ADUser -Name $user.displayName `
                -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName `
                -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName `
                -GivenName $user.givenname `
                -Surname $user.sn `
                -DisplayName $user.displayName `
                -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Pa`$`$w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force) `
                -PasswordNeverExpires $true `
                -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
                -Enabled $true
            write-host "- " $user.sAMAccountName "| Account Created" -ForegroundColor green
        } else {
            write-host "- " $user.sAMAccountName "|Account Exists" -ForegroundColor yellow
        }
    }
} catch {
    write-host "Error: "  $($_.CategoryInfo) -ForegroundColor red
    write-host "Message: " $($_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor red
}
write-host "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
write-host "End Process"
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've created the above code but I don't know the exact code to assign the user to either ou Sales, Management or Accounts.

The exact error is this: Error:  NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
Message:  The search filter cannot be recognized

Comment: `Get-ADUser` doesn't assign a user to anything; it simply retrieves user information from Active Directory. The error you are receiving indicates that there is a problem with your `LDAPFilter`; you need to correct this to get your call to work. I will note that I rarely - if ever - see `LDAPFilter` actually used; I find it easier to filter in other ways (and apparently, so do most people).[`Get-Help Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) will be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will take a look now and change the LDAPFilter

Comment: As it only appears that you are using the `sAMAccountName` to filter on, drop the `-LDAPFilter` entirely, and just use `-Identity $sAMAccountName`. See the link I gave you before resp. `Get-ADUser`, and pay special attention to the `-Identity` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your script, I don't see where you ever set the OU on the command.

You need to add a **-path** to your command to create the new user, and supply the name of the OU from your CSV..

For example:

```
    New-ADUser -Name "GlenJohn" -Path "OU=Sales"
```

Comment: Might also be easier, and faster, to put the new user create inside a "Try/Catch" block.  Try creating the account, and just trap the error.  That way, it's 1 call to AD instead of 2, but still with the same results.
(I've not tested, just thinking out loud here)